# Equivalent of SQL's CASE WHEN x THEN 1 ELSE NULL END in R

Tags: sql, r, pivot-table

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
working_df %>% 
  select(user_type, ride_length, day_of_week) %>%
  as.tibble() %>% 
  print(n = 3)
    # A tibble: 4,324,766 × 3
      user_type ride_length day_of_week
      <chr>           <dbl> <ord>      
    1 Casual          34355 Saturday   
    2 Member          32035 Monday     
    3 Casual          29271 Saturday
```

I want to create a table that provides the average ride length of the users per group per day.  I used SQL's CASE WHEN to divide the days of the week in separate columns.  See below:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(user_type,'combined') AS user_type,
    AVG(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(started_at) = 'Monday' THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,started_at, ended_at) ELSE NULL END) AS avg_ride_length_monday,
    AVG(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(started_at) = 'Tuesday' THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,started_at, ended_at) ELSE NULL END) AS avg_ride_length_tuesday,
    AVG(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(started_at) = 'Wednesday' THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,started_at, ended_at) ELSE NULL END) AS avg_ride_length_wednesday,
    AVG(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(started_at) = 'Thursday' THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,started_at, ended_at) ELSE NULL END) AS avg_ride_length_thursday,
    AVG(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(started_at) = 'Friday' THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,started_at, ended_at) ELSE NULL END) AS avg_ride_length_friday,
    AVG(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(started_at) = 'Saturday' THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,started_at, ended_at) ELSE NULL END) AS avg_ride_length_saturday,
    AVG(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(started_at) = 'Sunday' THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,started_at, ended_at) ELSE NULL END) AS avg_ride_length_sunday,
    AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,started_at, ended_at)) AS grand_total
FROM 
    bikes.work
GROUP BY 
    user_type WITH ROLLUP;
```

[image]

In my research, I found dplyr::case_when(), but I have only seen examples where values are counted in one column, and I want each day of the week to be spread out.  Does R have the ability to push results over several columns?

Edit: Thanks to your suggestions, I found this potential answer:

```
working_df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(c(user_type, day_of_week)), funs(as.character(.))) %>% 
  bind_rows(mutate(., user_type = "Combined")) %>% 
  bind_rows(mutate(., day_of_week = "Grand_Total")) %>% 
  group_by(user_type, day_of_week) %>% 
  summarize(avg_ride_length_min = mean(ride_length))  %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = day_of_week,
              values_from = avg_ride_length_min,
              names_prefix = "avg_ride_length_")

 user_type avg_ride_length_Friday avg_ride_length_Grand_Total avg_ride_length_Monday avg_ride_length_Saturday avg_ride_length_Sunday
  <chr>                      <dbl>                       <dbl>                  <dbl>                    <dbl>                  <dbl>
1 Casual                      22.6                        24.2                   25.0                     27.0                   27.5
2 Combined                    16.5                        17.3                   16.8                     20.9                   20.8
3 Member                      12.4                        12.6                   12.2                     14.2                   14.0
  avg_ride_length_Thursday avg_ride_length_Tuesday avg_ride_length_Wednesday
                     <dbl>                   <dbl>                     <dbl>
1                     21.6                    21.6                      20.9
2                     15.5                    15.1                      14.9
3                     12.2                    11.9                      12.0
```

Comment: Technically, your SQL is running the conditional aggregation to transform data from long to wide formats. Research the many long to wide methods in R in base, tidy, and data.table flavors.

Comment: Hi Parfait. I will play around with those today. Hopefully I can filter out those results and get my result. Will let you know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer with tidier results:

```
working_df %>%
  mutate(across(c(user_type, day_of_week), as.character)) %>% 
  bind_rows(mutate(., user_type = "United")) %>% 
  bind_rows(mutate(., day_of_week = "gt")) %>% 
  group_by(user_type, day_of_week) %>% 
  summarize(avg_ride_length_min = mean(ride_length))  %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = day_of_week,
              values_from = avg_ride_length_min,
              names_prefix = "avg_ride_length_") %>% 
  select("user_type", "avg_ride_length_Monday", "avg_ride_length_Tuesday", "avg_ride_length_Wednesday", "avg_ride_length_Thursday", "avg_ride_length_Friday", "avg_ride_length_Saturday", "avg_ride_length_Sunday", "avg_ride_length_gt")
    
    user_type avg_ride_length_Monday avg_ride_length_Tuesday avg_ride_length_Wednesday avg_ride_length_Thursday avg_ride_length_Friday
  <chr>                      <dbl>                   <dbl>                     <dbl>                    <dbl>                  <dbl>
1 Casual                      25.0                    21.6                      20.9                     21.6                   22.6
2 Member                      12.2                    11.9                      12.0                     12.2                   12.4
3 United                      16.8                    15.1                      14.9                     15.5                   16.5
  avg_ride_length_Saturday avg_ride_length_Sunday avg_ride_length_gt
                     <dbl>                  <dbl>              <dbl>
1                     27.0                   27.5               24.2
2                     14.2                   14.0               12.6
3                     20.9                   20.8               17.3
```

For some reason, `bind_rows` changes the row order alphabetically.  I wasn't able to change that, so I changed the last row from "Combined" to "United"

Answer (score 0):

We could try something like this:

Here we first calculate the avg_ride_length in long format, then we transform to wide wide format with pivot_wider() function:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

working_df %>%
  group_by(user_type, day_of_week) %>%
  summarise(avg_ride_length = mean(ride_length)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = day_of_week, 
              values_from = avg_ride_length,
              names_prefix = "avg_rige_length_")
```

data:

```
working_df <- structure(list(user_type = c("Casual", "Member", "Casual"), ride_length = c(34355L, 
32035L, 29271L), day_of_week = c("Saturday", "Monday", "Saturday"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```

Comment: I think the trickier thing in the question is that the OP also wants a column with the avg across all days, and a row with the avg across all user types.

Comment: You are right. I will try to figure out!

Comment: @TarJae    `working_df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(c(user_type, day_of_week)), funs(as.character(.))) %>% 
  bind_rows(mutate(., user_type = "Combined")) %>% 
  bind_rows(mutate(., day_of_week = "Total")) %>% 
  group_by(user_type, day_of_week) %>% 
  summarize(avg_ride_length_min = mean(ride_length))  %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = day_of_week,
              values_from = avg_ride_length_min,
              names_prefix = "avg_ride_length_")`

Comment: @KennySmith. Perfect. Please add this as an answer!

Comment: @TarJae sounds great.  I will try to change it to mutate across and submit